# Get 20 most frequent pairs(2/2) and triplets(3/3) of numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the most frequent pairs and triplets(3/3) of numbers, my table looks like this:

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | nr1  | nr2  | nr3  | nr4  | nr5  | nr6  | nr7  | nr8  | nr9  | nr10 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1  | 1    | 39   | 19   | 23   | 28   | 80   | 3    | 42   | 60   | 32   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | 43   | 18   | 3    | 24   | 29   | 33   | 15   | 1    | 61   | 80   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 3  | 11   | 25   | 33   | 2    | 30   | 3    | 1    | 44   | 62   | 78   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I want to know whats the top 3 most frequent pairs or triplets of numbers from all my rows.

Example :

1,3 (3 times)

1,80 (2 times)

3,80 (2 times)
1,3,80 (2 times)

I could try to add the numbers in order like 1,2,3 and then pull them from database but still the script I came up with is bad and takes hours to check 10000 lines

Any idea is welcome..
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are the numbers limited in any way? Maybe 1 to let's say 100?

Comment: yes, they are 1 to 90

Comment: can a same row have duplicate values? like two 80's ?

Comment: no only unique numbers on each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpivot your table, but mysql doesnt have unpivot function so you do

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b8cd/10)**

```
CREATE TABLE unpivot
SELECT *
FROM ( 
        SELECT id, nr1 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr2 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr3 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr4 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr5 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr6 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr7 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr8 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr9 as n_value FROM tuple union all 
        SELECT id, nr10 as n_value FROM tuple
     ) as T
```

Now look for number of pairs doing a join with itself.

```
SELECT n1, n2, count(*) as total
FROM 
    (
    SELECT up1.n_value as n1, up2.n_value as n2
    FROM unpivot up1
    JOIN unpivot up2
      ON up1.`id` = up2.`id`        
     AND up1.n_value < up2.n_value  
   ) T
GROUP BY n1, n2
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 3;
```

for triplets you join the table three times

```
SELECT n1, n2, n3, count(*) as total
FROM 
    (
    SELECT up1.n_value as n1, up2.n_value as n2, up3.n_value as n3
    FROM unpivot up1
    JOIN unpivot up2
      ON up1.`id` = up2.`id`        
     AND up1.n_value < up2.n_value  
     JOIN unpivot up3
      ON up2.`id` = up3.`id`        
     AND up2.n_value < up3.n_value  
   ) T
GROUP BY n1, n2, n3
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 3;
```

UPDATE:

I did my testing on postgresql

Create 50k rows, with random values from 1 to 90

After create the index the query only need 2 sec to complete.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the idea but i don't really understand the query... specially the part SELECT up1.n_value ? i get error there

Comment: Yeah, i have tested this morning and everything looks good but i got to the same problem... extremely slow when I have a 50k records :( The idea with unpivot is great but is still slow.

Comment: did you setup the index? can you share the `explain plan` ??

Comment: Check my update, I try it on postgres and only need 2 sec

Comment: Wow! I been trying all night to figure out what to do. Seems I have a problem with my computer then because I try it on my laptop and after 6 hours was still not done. I did exactly as you show and takes forever :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I do believe your answer is the right way to do it. From here on is my problem... probably hardware or something. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, tested on postgresql too and WHAT THE HELL!! 2 sec :) probably my mysql server is broken... thank you very much for the help! Great, great, great man! Don't have to say smart too because that's obvious :) Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks, I learn something from it too. Have to ask how create the sample data to test the query, lucky I post a question here and get a great answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665448/create-10-different-random-numbers

Comment: Thank you very much anyway :) I did have another question but i just figure it out... I am a little sick so hard to think. Thank you again.