# Create 10 different random numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, postgresql-9.2

I want generate some random data. ~50k rows

Every row have ID autonumeric and 10 numeric values from 1 to 90.

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | nr1  | nr2  | nr3  | nr4  | nr5  | nr6  | nr7  | nr8  | nr9  | nr10 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1  | 1    | 39   | 19   | 23   | 28   | 80   | 3    | 42   | 60   | 32   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | 43   | 18   | 3    | 24   | 29   | 33   | 15   | 1    | 61   | 80   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 3  | 11   | 25   | 33   | 2    | 30   | 3    | 1    | 44   | 62   | 78   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So each row need to have 10 different values.

I could generate 10 random numbers but compare all 10 between them self to make sure there isn't duplicates values take a lot of time.

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr1,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr2,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr3,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr4,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr5,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr6,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr7,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr8,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr9,
       trunc(random() * 89 + 1) as nr10
FROM generate_series(1,50);
```

So what is the more efficient way to perform that task.

Comment: What is your question, and what have you tried?

Comment: I generate 10 random number and then compare there are not duplicated. The question is if there is a fast method.

Comment: Please you show the code you used to do that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If you need SQL Server version **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/420820?Rowsnumber=50000&Maxvalue=90)** :)

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks I belive can translate that to postgres as well.

Comment: Do you care if two rows have the same set of 10 values?

Comment: @RickJames For this case didnt matter. I only need same row doesnt have duplicate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
-- INSERT INTO table( ...... )
CREATE TABLE test111 AS
SELECT 
       max( case when rn = 1 then nr end ) nr1,
       max( case when rn = 2 then nr end ) nr2,
       max( case when rn = 3 then nr end ) nr3,
       max( case when rn = 4 then nr end ) nr4,
       max( case when rn = 5 then nr end ) nr5,
       max( case when rn = 6 then nr end ) nr6,
       max( case when rn = 7 then nr end ) nr7,
       max( case when rn = 8 then nr end ) nr8,
       max( case when rn = 9 then nr end ) nr9,
       max( case when rn = 10 then nr end ) nr10
FROM generate_series(1,50000) id,
LATERAL ( 
  SELECT nr,
         row_number() over ( ORDER BY id * random() ) rn
  FROM generate_series(1,90) nr
)  x
GROUP BY id
```

This `CREATE TABLE` query takes on my PC about 8-9 seconds:
`Query OK, 50000 rows affected (execution time: 8,016 sec; total time: 8,016 sec)`

---

**EDIT - a version for PostgreSQL version <= 9.2**

---

```
CREATE TABLE test222 AS
SELECT        
       max( case when rn = 1 then nr end ) nr1,
       max( case when rn = 2 then nr end ) nr2,
       max( case when rn = 3 then nr end ) nr3,
       max( case when rn = 4 then nr end ) nr4,
       max( case when rn = 5 then nr end ) nr5,
       max( case when rn = 6 then nr end ) nr6,
       max( case when rn = 7 then nr end ) nr7,
       max( case when rn = 8 then nr end ) nr8,
       max( case when rn = 9 then nr end ) nr9,
       max( case when rn = 10 then nr end ) nr10
FROM (
    SELECT id, nr, row_number() over (partition by id order by random()) rn 
    FROM generate_series(1,50000) id
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT *  FROM generate_series(1,90) nr
    ) x
) y
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY id
```

This version takes about 7-8 seconds on my PC:
`Query OK, 50000 rows affected (execution time: 7,516 sec; total time: 7,516 sec)`

Comment: looks great, but `LATERAL` keyword was introduce in 9.3, and Im with 9.2 on this pc. I will try in another server later. Or maybe you can rewrite it without it, anyway I got the idea and working on a similar solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer - added a version for PostgreSQL <= 9.2

Answer (score 2):

Why not randomize the order of the numbers in the range you want (say 1,100), and then use the first 10.

A loop and a pivot will do it:

```
declare @result table (id int, nr1 int, nr2 int, nr3 int, nr4 int, nr5 int, nr6 int, nr7 int, nr8 int, nr9 int, nr10 int)

declare @numberSet table (n int)
declare @i table (rw int,rnk int, n int)

insert into @numberset
SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 100


declare @l int
set @l = 0

WHILE (@l < 50000)
BEGIN
    insert into @i
    select top 10 @l+1,rank() over (order by id), n from (select newid() id , n from @numberset ) b
    SELECT @l = @l + 1
END

INSERT INTO @result
SELECT  rw,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
FROM (SELECT rw, n,rnk from @i) as sourcetable
PIVOT
(max(n) for rnk in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) as pivottable;

SELECT * FROM @result
```

Comment: Sound good. I can do the randomize order, how I put that in a bucle to insert 50k rows?

Comment: Sorry, what is a bucle?

Comment: sorry, I mean a Loop. Funny how brain didnt translate that :)

Comment: This answer uses SQL Server and question is about Postgresql. Anyway loop is redundant. See my **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/420820?Rowsnumber=50000&Maxvalue=90)**. As you see, there is posibility to combine everything to one statement (remove variables, use SELECT INTO) :)